# CMake differences between linking when target is a library vs executable

Tags: cmake

The following correctly links the executable to the protobuffer.

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(proto_srcs proto_hdrs simple.proto
add_executable(executable a.cc "${proto_srcs}")
target_link_libraries(executable "${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}")
```

The following does not correctly link the libraries.

```
protobuf_generate_cpp(proto_srcs proto_hdrs simple.proto
add_library(proto_lib "${proto_srcs}")
target_link_libraries(proto_lib "${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}")
...
target_link_libraries(some_executable proto_lib)
```

The issue appears to be in the handling of debug vs optimized libraries.  In the first this is properly handled, while in the second it attempts to link to the debug/optimized library string, error follows.

```
ld: library not found for -loptimized;/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.dylib;debug;/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
```

I've tried playing with the quoting of arguments and changing the type of library being created, but I'm at a loss.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove doublequotes around `${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}`, they make CMake treat list variable as plain string.

Comment: Thanks, thought I had tried that.  I'm curious, is there any reason treating the libraries as a string would work with the executable target but not with the library target?


I can venture a guess that in the library it treats it as a cmake target name if it's a string where as in the executable, it recognizes the "special" nature of the string, but that's a pretty wild guess.